# How to code a conditional counter?

Tags: c++, c, counter, reset

**How to code a conditional counter ?**

I'm trying to code a simple conditional counter for my project and I came across some problems. The counter needs to be able to count and reset.

Every time a random number is chosen from 1~100 equals to 1, the counter will +1 so I can know how many times 1 has appeared over a period of time. But my code doesn't work because every time the condition hasn't been met, "count" will go back to zero instead of memorizing how many times 1 has appeared. And I can't seem to be able to add reset to this code.

```
int count = 0;
random = rand() % 100 + 1;  

if(random == 1)
{
    count = count + 1;
}
Print (count);
```

Comment: Do you have a loop of some sort? Show us the surrounding code. See the help page on how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `count` more globally.

You seem to be expecting its lifetime to extend beyond the call to the above subroutine, but yet you reinitialize `int count = 0;` each time you call for a new random int

Comment: Exactly how do you do that?

Comment: @Jim: you have multiple options, including (1) pass the counter as a pointer (or, in C++, as a reference) to the function, (2) make the variable a file scope static (or, in C++, in the anonymous namespace), or (3) make the variable a function scope static variable.  The disadvantage of option 3 is that there's no easy way to get at the variable to either print it or reset it — it is better to have the variable at file (anonymous namespace) scope and manage it from there.